# "turn of the time"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I searched for this phrase but didn't find it any where 
"where are those brave warriors;"***the turn of the time*** has rendered all of them low and powerless.Does it mean"change of time"? Also what is being "low"referred to?

Comment: Where did you find this quote? It's not quite either idiomatic or literary.

Comment: @StoneyB although it's definitely redolent of literariness.

Comment: The idiom "turn of the **tide**" may have been intended (i.e. a change in circumstances).

Comment: I suspect it was supposed to be "the turn of time", not "of **the** time".  It would be a kind of poetic, metaphorical usage, indicating the changes brought by time.

Comment: I thought so ,but wasn't sure about it

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be an idiom in English - or at least not one that Google recognizes. Without more context it's hard to tell what it means exactly - but my guess would be that it's analogous to the phrase **[the turn of the century](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-of-the-century)**:

> the time when a particular century ends and another begins

So in the broad sense, "the turn of the time" would mean "the time going forward; the progression of time".

As to your other question, "low" can mean "unhappy, exhausted" (as in "he was feeling a bit low today"). So those people would be sad and lacking the energy.

Comment: so, the progression of time has changed things- correct?